# Help with System Tray Whitelisting?

Tags: unity, launcher, indicator, bumblebee

I'm running 13.04 stock. I use Cryptkeeper and Davmail for access to things. [How to get the systray Whitelist back in Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html) is the method I used to get it working.

Everything was going swimmingly, then I decided to upgrade Bumblebee and Primus to try and get better performance in games.

Since I was running the old version of Primus, I followed the directions, did a purge of that PPA, removed Bumblebee and then `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`... you know, normal stuff.

When I rebooted, Logon was off. I had no launcher or dash or anything after login.
Ugh, OK. I screwed something up with Unity. So, I reset Unity.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

So that got my launcher and dash back up, although at default settings.
Now, I can't seem to get the system tray whitelist to work.

I can see the key existing in `dconf-editor`. If I try and manually force the change via console, I get this:

```
:~$ gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
No such schema 'com.canonical.Unity.Panel'
```

When I check, the PPA is still in my sources, as well as the packages seem to be installed. (http://ppa.launchpad.net/timekiller/unity-systrayfix/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/ ) is the URL to the path. Below is my installed package versions:

```
~$ dpkg --list | grep -i unity
ii  gir1.2-unity-5.0:i386                     6.90.2daily13.04.05-0ubuntu1         i386         GObject introspection data for the Unity library
ii  gnome-control-center-unity                1.2daily13.04.09-0ubuntu1            i386         change the settings of the Unity desktop
ii  hud                                       13.04.0daily13.04.03-0ubuntu1        i386         Backend for the Unity HUD
ii  libmeanwhile1                             1.0.2-4ubuntu2                       i386         open implementation of the Lotus Sametime Community Client protocol
ii  libufe-xidgetter0                         2.4.7bzr13.04.15-0ubuntu1            i386         Firefox extension: Unity Integration
ii  libunity-common                           6.90.2daily13.04.05-0ubuntu1         all          binding to get places into the launcher - common files
ii  libunity-core-6.0-5                       7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1    i386         Core library for the Unity interface.
ii  libunity-misc4                            4.0.5daily13.02.26-0ubuntu1          i386         Miscellaneous functions for Unity - shared library
ii  libunity-protocol-private0:i386           6.90.2daily13.04.05-0ubuntu1         i386         binding to get places into the launcher - private library
ii  libunity-webapps0                         2.5.0~daily13.03.18-0ubuntu1         i386         Web Apps integration with the Unity desktop
ii  libunity9:i386                            6.90.2daily13.04.05-0ubuntu1         i386         binding to get places into the launcher - shared library
ii  thunderbird-globalmenu                    17.0.8+build1-0ubuntu0.13.04.1       i386         Unity appmenu integration for Thunderbird
ii  unity                                     7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1    i386         Interface designed for efficiency of space and interaction.
ii  unity-asset-pool                          0.8.24daily13.04.24-0ubuntu1         all          Unity Assets Pool
ii  unity-common                              7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1    all          Common files for the Unity interface.
ii  unity-greeter                             13.04.2-0ubuntu1                     i386         Unity Greeter
ii  unity-lens-applications                   6.10.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1   i386         Application lens for unity
ii  unity-lens-files                          7.0~daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1           i386         File lens for unity
ii  unity-lens-friends                        0.1.1bzr13.04.12-0ubuntu1            i386         Friends Lens for unity
ii  unity-lens-music                          6.8.1daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1    i386         Music lens for unity
ii  unity-lens-photos                         0.9daily12.12.05-0ubuntu1            all          Unity Photos Lens
ii  unity-lens-shopping                       6.8.0daily13.03.04-0ubuntu1          i386         Shopping lens for unity
ii  unity-lens-video                          0.3.14daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1   i386         Unity Video lens
ii  unity-scope-gdrive                        0.8daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1            all          Google Drive scope for Unity
ii  unity-scope-musicstores                   6.8.1daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1    i386         Store music lens for unity
ii  unity-scope-video-remote                  0.3.14daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1   i386         Remote videos engine
ii  unity-services                            7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1    i386         Services for the Unity interface
rc  unity-webapps-common                      2.4.14-0ubuntu1                      all          Unity WebApp integration scripts
ii  unity-webapps-service                     2.5.0~daily13.03.18-0ubuntu1         i386         Service for Web Apps integration with the Unity desktop
ii  xul-ext-unity                             2.4.7bzr13.04.15-0ubuntu1            all          Firefox extension: Unity Integration
```

I'm at a loss as to (1) why it doesn't work, and (2) who I even ask for help.
So, uh, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

During upgrade you have installed latest version of Unity package (7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1) without whitelist support. Previously, you had 7.0.0daily13.04.18~13.04-0ubuntu1systray1. So, you could try to downgrade unity to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to apply the patch posted by timekiller and rebuild from source the lastest Unity 7.0 branch.

You'll have to download lots of -dev packages to rebuild unity, but here are the steps:

1. get the patch from here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/974480/comments/42
2. mkdir my-unity
3. cd my-unity
4. bzr branch lp:unity/7.0
5. cd unity
6. patch -p1 < path-to-saved-diff
7. debuild -i -us -uc -b
8. cd ..
9. dpkg -i *.deb (not all debs may be necessary, it depends if you have unity-2d)

It worked for me, YMMV, good luck.

May be that timekiller will update his PPA in the next days (I hope :-).

I really do not understand why Canonical is taking this way about Unity, lot of applications are not yet updated to use the AppIndicator (which is a good idea IMHO) and without the systray these applications are **completely unusable** (for me for example Druva inSync and 2XClient).

Answer (score 0):

I've setup a PPA with the latest Unity 7.0 daily 13.06.19 patched with the systray back in action :-)

https://launchpad.net/~liuk001/+archive/unity-systrayfix

It's my first PPA but it is working fine for me, if you enable it you should get the following packages updated:

```
ii  libunity-core-6.0-5  7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1ppa1      amd64        Core library for the Unity interface.
ii  unity                7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1ppa1      amd64        Interface designed for efficiency of space and interaction.
ii  unity-common         7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1ppa1      all          Common files for the Unity interface.
ii  unity-services       7.0.0daily13.06.19~13.04-0ubuntu1ppa1      amd64        Services for the Unity interface
```

YMMV
Ciao
Luca

Answer (score 0):

I maintain the ppa you used. With newer versions of unity, the com.canonical.Unity.Panel schema (where the whitelist lives) is getting ignored. Rather than deal with the cat and mouse game with Canonical, I have hardcoded a global whitelist in my newer builds. Now, *ALL* systray applications will display, eliminating the need for the whitelist. As long as you are still using my ppa, just update and restart unity. You'll be all set.